# jQuery - regex for integer and comma(s) - should only accept hundreds, thousands and millions

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

Max value should be 99,999,999 (no period at the end). So it should accept:

- 123
- 1,234
- 10,000
- 100,000
- 1,000,000
- 99,000,000
- etc.

I found this code that does if perfectly for floats:

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="numberOnly" name="example" value="" required>
```

jQuery:

```
 $('.numberOnly').keyup(function() {
  var valid = /^\-?\d+\.\d*$|^\-?[\d]*$/;
  var number = /\-\d+\.\d*|\-[\d]*|[\d]+\.[\d]*|[\d]+/;
  if (!valid.test($(this).val())) {
   var n = this.value.match(number);
   this.value = n ? n[0] : '';
  }
 });
```

The values it accepts are: **1.1**, **.1**, **1** (And they can even be negative values.)

Whenever a user types an invalid value, for example **1..**, it automatically deletes the invalid value which in this case is the second dot.

I wanted to do something similar for my question. Here's what I have so far but obviously it's not working.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="millions" name="example2" value="" required>
```

jQuery:

```
 $('.millions').keyup(function() {
  var valid = /^(\d[0-0]{0,3}[\,]\d{0,9}[\,])?\d{0,9}$/;
  var number = /\d{0,9}[\,](\d{0,9}[\,]\d{0,9})?/;
  if (!valid.test($(this).val())) {
   var n = this.value.match(number);
   this.value = n ? n[0] : '';
  }
 });
```

In addition to wanting to know the correct regex format that I need, can anyone also explain what are **valid** and **number** variables used for?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't recommend having your JS change the field's value from a key handler, because changing the value moves the position of the cursor - very annoying for users trying to edit an existing value. If you feel you must do this you should add extra code to retain the cursor position. Regarding use of `valid` and `number` in the code shown, I think the idea is that if the string as a whole is invalid but does contain a valid number within the string then the field is automatically updated to just keep the number part.

Comment: @nnnnnn This will be used in the backend, so we don't worry that much about the position of the cursor. Thanks about the `valid` and `number` bit, that makes sense. Do you happen to know the correct regex combination?

Answer (score 0):

The `valid` pattern is the one you're interested in for server side checking. It's the pattern used to check that the whole string conforms to your requirements. The `number` pattern is the one used to do replacement when the user types an illegal character. The `number` pattern needs to be more relaxed to allow the user to enter subsequences of valid patterns (e.g. *1,0*) which the user may then complete to a valid pattern.

This pattern will do what you require:

```
var valid = /^([1-9]\d?(,\d{3}){0,2}|[1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})?|0)$/;
```

Breaking it down:

- `^(` - start of line
- `[1-9]\d{0,2}` - first group starts with a non-zero digit followed by 0-1 digits
- `(,\d{3}){0,2}` - 0-2 or comma separated groups of three digits
- `|[1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})?` - or a three digit leading group followed by a three digit trailing group
- `|0` - "0" by itself is valid
- `)$` - end of line

The `number` pattern is more complicated as it has to allow a trailing comma and allow groups of less than three digits at the end.

Comment: Thank you so much, really helpful and close! I noticed that it still accepted values that are past 99,999,999 (which is the max value required). I reckon that `number` should be tweaked a bit.

Comment: Ah. I didn't notice the max value requirement. That will be harder.

Comment: A good example is the Loan Amount field on this site: https://mortgage.redbrick.sg/package?r=site/new-loan